# Back4App, how to update a relational data array

Tags: java, android, android-studio, saving-data, back4app

Whenever I've tried to save Reviews class data to my Post class, the terminal output this message and i'm not sure how to update the relational data in back4app correctly Here is the error message.
com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

```
package com.example.rentahome.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rentahome.Post;
import com.example.rentahome.R;
import com.example.rentahome.ReviewAdapter;
import com.example.rentahome.Reviews;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link ReviewFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ReviewFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    public Post loadpost;
    public EditText description;
    public RatingBar ratingBar;
    public Button submit;

    public void updatePost(Post post){
        loadpost = post;
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public ReviewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ReviewFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ReviewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ReviewFragment fragment = new ReviewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);




        description = view.findViewById(R.id.submitReview_description);
        ratingBar = view.findViewById(R.id.submitReview_ratingbar);
        submit = view.findViewById(R.id.submitReview_submitbtn);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = loadpost.getRelation("Reviews");

                if(ratingBar.getNumStars() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Rate the house!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(description.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Describe the house!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    ParseObject temp = ParseObject.create("Reviews");
                    temp.put("Description",description.getText().toString());
                    temp.put("author", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    temp.put("likesCount",0);
                    temp.put("dislikesCount",0);
                    temp.put("rating", (float)ratingBar.getNumStars());


                    temp.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {

                        }
                    });


                    relation.add(temp);


                    loadpost.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if(e!=null){
                                Log.e("ReviewFragment","Issue with saving posts..", e);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    Homefragment nextFrag= new Homefragment();

                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.flContainer, nextFrag)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The basic idea was to grab a loadpost from existing post data and create a Reviews object and then appending it to the loadpost and saving it.
I used this documentation to try to find out my solution
https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-data

Answer (score 0):

```
Reviews temp2 = new Reviews();
                    temp2.setAuthor(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    temp2.setDescription(description.getText().toString());
                    temp2.setRating((float)ratingBar.getNumStars());
                    temp2.setdislikesCount(0);
                    temp2.setlikesCount(0);
                    temp2.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if(e!=null){
                                Log.e("ReviewFragment","Issue with saving posts..", e);
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }

                            relation.add(temp2);
                            loadpost.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if(e!=null){
                                        Log.e("ReviewFragment","Issue with saving posts..", e);
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
```

All I had to do was to call a object and save it inside the save in background function.